# Get next page using scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm interested in get contractors data for atlanta from this page:

http://www.1800contractor.com/d.Atlanta.GA.html?link_id=3658

So for I can open the links for the categories

'Additions & Remodeling'
'Architects & Engineers'
'Fountains & Ponds'
......
.....
.....

But I can open only the first page:

http://www.1800contractor.com/d.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html?startingIndex=0&showDirectory=true

I'm trying to open get the next one with the links of the 'Next' button:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[8]/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
request = scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
yield request
```

But it makes no difference.

This is the code of my spider:

```
import scrapy


class Spider_1800(scrapy.Spider):
    name = '1800contractor'
    allowed_domains = ['1800contractor.com']
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.1800contractor.com/d.Atlanta.GA.html?link_id=3658',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tr/td[2]/table/tr[6]/td/table/tr[2]/td/b/a/@href').extract()

        for url in urls:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            request = scrapy.Request(
                absolute_url, callback=self.parse_contractors)
            yield request

        # process next page

        next_page_url = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[8]/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        request = scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
        yield request

    def parse_contractors(self, response):
        name = response.xpath(
            '/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[5]/td/table/tr[1]/td/b/a/@href').extract()
        contrator = {
           'name': name,

            'url': response.url}
        yield contrator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not paginating the right request, `parse` handles the request generated with the urls in `start_urls`, which means that you need to enter each category in http://www.1800contractor.com/d.Atlanta.GA.html?link_id=3658 first.

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tr/td[2]/table/tr[6]/td/table/tr[2]/td/b/a/@href').extract()

    for url in urls:
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
        request = scrapy.Request(
            absolute_url, callback=self.parse_contractors)
        yield request

def parse_contractors(self, response):
    name = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[5]/td/table/tr[1]/td/b/a/@href').extract()
    contrator = {
       'name': name,

        'url': response.url}
    yield contrator

    next_page_url = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[8]/td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url, callback=self.parse_contractors)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result

Comment: please check updated answer, looks like you were handling the wrong request on your callback methods

Answer (score 0):

After hitting start_url your xpath for picking url for contractors are not working. Next page is present on contractor page therefore its called after contractor url. this will work for you

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.xpath('//table//*[@class="hiCatNaked"]').extract()

    for url in urls:
      absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
      request = scrapy.Request(
        absolute_url, callback=self.parse_contractors)
      yield request

def parse_contractors(self, response):
    name=response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/center/table/tr[5]/td/table/tr[1]/td/b/a/@href').extract()

    contrator = {
   'name': name,
    'url': response.url}
    yield contrator

    next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[b[contains(.,'Next')]]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url, callback=self.parse_contractors)
```